# Getting style from any offset in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, styling, jtextpane

Is there a way to get `Style`, a style name or just even compare whether `Style` at a certain position of `JTextPane` with the style I gave the text when inserting? Because for my purpose I created custom `JTextPane`, `StyledDocument` and `DocumentFilter`. So I could choose `Style` to be used for say regular letters and another Style for numbers. I have also toggle button which while toggled sets `DocumentFilter` to format numbers differently and while not toggled numbers format regularly so at the end you can't distinguish which numbers have been affected just according to `JTextPane's getText()` method. Therefore the only way would be to compare styles which I have both regular and special number style as constants. Only thing I need to come up with is how to get Style for each character.

I know there is `JTextPane's` method to get AttributeSet from the caret's position called `getCharacterAttributes()` but I think it's no use for my issue.

Is it necessary to include code example? I don't think it's difficult to imagine. If you want me I will include it though.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try calling [`StyledDocument.getCharacterElement(pos)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html#getCharacterElement(int)) to get the character element at that position and then call [`Element.getAttributes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Element.html#getAttributes()) to get its attribute set.

The [`AttributeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AttributeSet.html) contains styles which you can retrieve using methods provided by [`StyleConstants`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleConstants.html).

Comment: thank you, using StyledDocument.getCharacterElement(pos).getAttributes().containsAttributs() I was finnally able to make it work, thx again!